# Ошибка компиляции missing terminating ' "" ' character C++

Tags: c++, циклы, векторы

Вот код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    vector<double> v;
    v.push_back(2.7);
    v.push_back(5.6);
    v.push_back(7.9);

    for(int = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
        cout << "v[" << i << "]==" << v[i] << "\n";
    }
}
```

При компиляции пишет

> "C:\Users\Nikita\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp : 15 : 41:
>   Waring: missing terminating ' "" ' character [-Winvalid-pp-token]

```
cout << "v[" << i << "]==" << v[i] << "\n";
                              ^
```

> "C:\Users\Nikita\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp : 15 : 41:
>   error: expected expression
>   1error and 1 waring generated

Объясните пожалуйста почему так происходит? Я начинающий и ёщё учусь.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Послушайте, ну можно хотя бы 5 минут подумать, прежде чем бежать спрашивать?

```
for(int = 0;
```

Какую переменную вы тут объявляете?

Все остальное отлично компилируется: https://ideone.com/6fFF6x

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
```

Я не уверен, но мне кажется нужно объявить переменную.